# Not able to start Svelte

Tags: svelte

Installed svelte using the below command:

When I try to run `npm run dev` I get the bellow error:

> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev /Working/Svelte/first-app
>   run-p start:dev autobuild
>
> svelte-app@1.0.0 autobuild /Working/Svelte/first-app
>   rollup -c -w
>
> svelte-app@1.0.0 start:dev /Working/Svelte/first-app
>   sirv public --dev
>
> events.js:180
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1412:12)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:17) {
>     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
>     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
>     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>     hostname: 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0'

My Node version is - v12.6.0, OS MacOS Mojave

Can anybody help me out to figure what's wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This seems like an dns issue. Try running ```unset host``` in terminal, then run ```npm run dev```

Comment: @GAGANDEEP SINGH. Ran `unset host` and then `npm run dev`. Same error :(.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on Linux (OpenSUSE 15.1) and managed to fix it, but I haven't tried it on MacOS. The basic issue seems to be that the local machine's hostname is not resolved to an IP. For me it turned out it was because I had set a custom hostname, but did not update `/etc/hosts`, so dns.js failed to resolve it. So basically I had an existing custom hostname:

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
mycustomhostname
```

And I edited `/etc/hosts` from:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

...
```

To:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       mycustomhostname


...
```

And Svelte managed to start after that.

Again, not sure if the same would work on MacOS, but there might be another way to get it to resolve your hostname.

EDIT: There is also a simpler way that might work, if you run

```
export HOST=localhost
```

then

```
npm run dev
```

It will bind to `localhost` instead of trying to use the custom hostname.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Quickest solution might actually be `unset HOST` as suggested before. It looks like it goes by that variable, but defaults to `localhost`.

Comment: i have opensuse too ..
this is worked for me (export HOST=localhost) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, I just did a `unset HOST` at my terminal. Then `npm run dev` executed without problems.